# cURL 35 error when connecting to http website

Tags: php, curl

I couldn't find answer on this questions. Sometimes* while trying to retrieve data from http (NOT https) site I get 35 error - SSL connect error. 
URL that I'm trying to reach is ie. http://www.aliexpress.com/item//32566080839.html. Then i get redirected to "full url": http://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-Sport-Headband-Bike-Halloween-Skull-face-mask-balaclava-Skull-Bandana-Paintball-Ski-Motorcycle-Helmet-Neck/32566080839.html

My cURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://aliexpress.com/item//'. $id .'.html');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
```

I've been trying to add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);` but it doesn't help. 
Why http site gives a 35 error? Is it normal?
Is it possible that aliexpress i blocking my requests?

Sometimes I also get 28 error which is timeout reached - even with 10 seconds timeout.

***Sometimes** - I mean it's working for a few hours then not working for about 10 minutes and then still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `spider` on their site using the Id. And as a consequence the site blocks you. As you are referring to `SSL` error, it is very likely that during the blockade period they are redirecting you to an error page that starts with `https://`

For the debugging purpose you can enable the verbose mode and observe the header and you'll find what is inside the `Location:` response header.

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Comment: Well, some kind of spider indeed. Thanks for the tip, I'll try it next time error will appear.

Comment: Yup, you were right. In debug log I see that there is redirect to https with url like "anti-spider" ;)

Comment: @instead how did you get arround it, I'm too being redirected to antispider page after some time of running my spider by using only ID?

Comment: @kecman Actually I didn't. After discovering anti-spider location I abandoned functionality that needed use of CURL. BUT in this specific case I also discovered that there is limit of requests per some period of time. It was about 150 requests per hour If i recall right. I didn't developed it though. Nevertheles it might be some tip.

Comment: @instead thanks a lot, that info about 150 req/hr means a lot to me, as I mostly ran batches with around 150 IDs.